# Using an instance more than once when creating a MovieClip through composition

Tags: actionscript-3

FURTHER EDIT: Added second parameter to clarify that TreeGenerator is using pre-created parts from the Sprites passed through the parameter, not generating them.

EDIT: I've attempted to change the code away from using "shapes" and "MovieClips" as that was kind of confusing and obscuring the issue I was having.

I'm trying to create a Sprite by using that parts of other Sprites. I've posted some code that illustrates what I'm trying to do:

```
public class TreeGenerator extends Sprite 
{
    private var _leaf:Sprite
    private var _branch:Sprite
    private var _trunk:Sprite
    //these are separately drawn and instantiated in other sprites,
    //one of which will be passed through in the parameters

    public var thumbnail:Sprite

    public function TreeGenerator($preCreatedTreeOne:Sprite, $preCreatedTreeTwo:Sprite) 
    {
        _leaf = $preCreatedTreeOne.leaf;
        _branch = $preCreatedTreeTwo.branch;
        _trunk = $preCreatedTreeOne.trunk;

        thumbnail = $preCreatedTreeOne.leaf;
        //just uses the leaf for this example

        this.addchild(_leaf);
        _leaf.y = 30;
        this.addchild(_branch);
        _branch.y = 20;
        this.addchild(_trunk);
        _trunk.y = 10;
        //this "puts together" the tree image (though very
        //simply with just y for example purposes)

        this.addchild(thumbnail);
        thumbnail.y = 40;
        //this thumbnail is supposed to be a separate object that can also
        //be interacted with but this example neglects the event listeners.
        //the important thing here is the setting of the y to 40, which 
        //overwrites the y of 30 for _leaf.
    }
}
```

I'm passing through two Sprites already instantiated to $preCreatedTreeOne and $preCreatedTreeTwo that were created through an assortment of tree parts to choose from (large green leaf, small red leaf, thin branch, thick branch, etc.). Those sprites are drawn images, not images generated in code (say from a .swc library). When the user clicks a button after clicking on two trees on the stage, TreeGenerator will create another image of a tree, complete with leaf, branch, and trunk but this time using the parts from the two pre-created trees (and it would be dynamic, one click would generate a tree with green leaves from tree one, thick branches from tree two, and a thin trunk from tree one, whichever combination of two trees chosen as "one" or "two"). There would also be a separate thumbnail that could be interacted with independently (though that code is omitted in the example).

However, when I run the code, I see that the y coordinate value for _leaf gets overridden by thumbnail, because I now realize that both are now $preCreatedTreeOne.leaf.

How do I "take" additional instances (or copies) of $preCreatedTreeOne.leaf from $preCreatedTreeOne so that I can independently manipulate them when I store them in different variables?

Comment: Why do you pass in a `MovieClip` as a parameter? Where do these sets of shapes come from? You say the user chooses them: how does he do that?

Comment: You use MovieClip everywhere but which are really MovieClip? For example NewShape is definitely not one so what else is not a MovieClip? (has no timeline)

Comment: I guess you could just use "Sprite" instead. I'm not an advanced writer with Actionscript 3 (or programming in general). However, you still get the same problem even with sprites. Changing the x, y, scaleX, etc. of the thumbnail also affects _circle (note: the "shapes" are not important, more generally, I'm trying to use drawn images that are then put together as one image in this class, dynamically, say whenever the user clicks a button for example). I need to be able to manipulate _circle and thumbnail separately.

Answer (score 0):

### [IGraphicsData](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/IGraphicsData.html)

You can create objects that correspond to calls to methods of the drawing API. They all implement the above interface. You can then group them in a `Vector.<IGraphicsData>` and shove them into [`drawGraphicsData()`](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#drawGraphicsData()) to get your stuff drawn in a `Graphics` object.

You are not passing around the meal, but its recipe. You can then cook as many meals according to the recipe as you like.

Since FP 11.6 you can also query `Vector.<IGraphicsData>` from a `Graphics` object via [`readGraphicsData()`](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#readGraphicsData())

> **disclaimer:** I hacked together a modified version of your example code in wonder.fl because I don't have a compiler installed, please implement this properly with separate class files and not internal classes.
>
> My Flash Player is from back in the day when it was still cool to have it and thus a little old (11.2), which means I couldn't actually test the code with `readGraphicsData()`, which is why I pass the triangle list to all 3 parameters.

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Shape;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.IGraphicsData;
    import flash.display.GraphicsPath;
    import flash.display.GraphicsSolidFill;
    
    import flash.display.GraphicsEndFill;
    
    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        public function Main() 
        {
            
            // assemble Vector.<IGraphicsData> manually for triangle
            var triangle:GraphicsPath = new GraphicsPath();
            var triangleHeight:uint = 30; 
            triangle.moveTo(triangleHeight / 2, 0); 
            triangle.lineTo(triangleHeight, triangleHeight); 
            triangle.lineTo(0, triangleHeight); 
            triangle.lineTo(triangleHeight / 2, 0);
            
            var commands:Vector.<IGraphicsData> = new <IGraphicsData>[new GraphicsSolidFill(0xff0000), triangle, new GraphicsEndFill()];

            addChild(new ShapeSet(commands, commands, commands));
            
            // since FP 11.6 the following is also possible
            
            // assemble Vector.<IGraphicsData> from existing Graphics object in Shape
            var square:Shape = new Shape();
            square.graphics.beginFill(0xff00);
            square.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 30, 30);
            square.graphics.endFill();
            
             addChild(new ShapeSet(square.graphics.readGraphicsData(), commands, commands));
        }
    }
}
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.display.IGraphicsData;

internal class ShapeSet extends Sprite
{
    private var _square:Shape;
    private var _triangle:Shape;    
    private var _thumbnail:Shape;

    public function ShapeSet(square:Vector.<IGraphicsData>, triangle:Vector.<IGraphicsData>,  thumbnail:Vector.<IGraphicsData>) 
    {
        _square = new Shape();
        _triangle = new Shape();
        _thumbnail = new Shape();

        addChild(_square);
        _square.x = 10;
        addChild(_triangle);
        _triangle.x = 60;
        addChild(_thumbnail);
        _thumbnail.x = 90;
        
        _square.graphics.drawGraphicsData(square);
        _triangle.graphics.drawGraphicsData(triangle);
        _thumbnail.graphics.drawGraphicsData(thumbnail);
    }
}
```

If you want to pass only triangles to triangles, you should write a triangle class that encapsulates a `Vector.<IGraphicsData>` and ensures that it only contains data that represents a triangle. How to do this is out of the scope of this question.

Comment: I guess the choice of using "shapes" was a poor example on my part. I should have been more clear: the code I posted was modified to use the fake "shape" MovieClips as I wanted to just focus down on the concept I was having trouble with. That concept was basically creating two different instances from one object that was passed through as a parameter.

To be more clear in my example, you could replace shapes with the pieces of a tree (leaves, branches, trunk, etc.) and there are different MovieClips for each (green large leaf, small red leaf, etc.) The NewShape would just build a tree.

Comment: The TreeGenerator (NewShape) would just be a way for me to dynamically create different trees whenever the user does something that requires a tree to be added to the scene. However, I also want to create a thumbnail of the tree (that can also be selected and separately modified, but that goes beyond the purview here). The problem is if I were to use the "leaf" object (which is actually a separately drawn image, not generated in code) from the passed through MovieClip for both the leaf on the tree and the thumbnail, they will overwrite each other (x, y, scaleX, etc.).

Comment: @CE.GOV: the problem is still the same. Did you bother trying my answer? Please explain why it doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: I am actually traveling and my current computer does not have my FlashDevelop installed. However, from what I can ascertain from your code (I admit, I am not an advanced programmer), ShapeSet (corresponds to TreeGenerator) generates the shapes within it (new Shape();) when it is added to the stage by Main (when given the command to create a shape in the parameter). However, for my problem, TreeGenerator is supposed to use parts from Sprites that were generated previously (perhaps also added to the stage earlier), that's why it's passed through the parameter. So TreeGenerator cannot use "new".

Comment: So in my edited version, first, TreeOne, TreeTwo (perhaps TreeThree, Tree...) would be created using Sprites (perhaps from a .swc library so for example TreeOne create a leaf with "new LargeGreenLeaf();", branches and trunk similarly). Second, when the user clicks on two trees on the stage and then clicks on a button, the two tree sprites will be passed into the two parameters. TreeGenerator will then take the leaf and trunk sprite from TreeOne and the branch sprite from TreeTwo and then generates a new tree. However, the issue I have is that I cannot use leaf for both the leaf and thumbnail.